# Using async and await in selenium protractor tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, async-await, protractor

How do I use async and await in protractor tests?

```
it('test async', function(){
    var value = 0;
    function asyncAction() {
        return browser.driver.wait(()=>true)
            .then(function () {
                console.log('a');
                return value++;
            });
    }
    //-Problem Area-
    async function doAwait(){
        await asyncAction();
        return asyncAction();
    }

    doAwait();

    protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute( () => {
        console.log('b');
        expect(value).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

output here is

- a
- b
- a

and value is 1 at time of expect
function doAwait(){
        await asyncAction();
        return asyncAction();
    }

I like to think of this as similar to

```
function doAwait(){
  asyncAction().then(()=>asyncAction());
}
```

Which works but the above async doAwait does not.  I believe this is because the generator breaks the ControlFlow of selenium.

Comment: You already got this "I believe this is because the generator breaks the ControlFlow of selenium."

Comment: I'm curious to know how you tested this. My IDE only supports until ECMA 6

Comment: require('babel-register')({
  plugins: ['transform-async-to-generator']
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this to the protractor configuration works:

```
var webdriver = require.main.require('selenium-webdriver');
Promise = webdriver.promise.Promise;
Object.assign(Promise, webdriver.promise);
Promise.resolve = Promise.fulfilled;
Promise.reject = Promise.rejected;
```

Though maybe not all promises are supposed to be managed promises?

Worth noting that the other solution requires wrapping each async function:

```
protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute( async () => {
    await asyncAction();
    return asyncAction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/angular/jasminewd#async-functions--await:

## `async` functions / `await`

`async` functions and the `await` keyword are likely coming in ES2017 (ES8), and available via several compilers. At the moment, they often break the WebDriver control flow. ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3037)). You can still use them, but if you do then you will have to use `await`/Promises for almost all your synchronization. See [spec/asyncAwaitAdapterSpec.ts](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/blob/jasminewd2/spec/asyncAwaitAdapterSpec.ts) and [spec/asyncAwaitErrorSpec.ts](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/blob/jasminewd2/spec/asyncAwaitErrorSpec.ts) for examples.